# PHP echo $this->item->link in a href not working - showing JObject->link

Tags: php, html, web

quick question as I'm pulling my hear out!

In a PHP file I have different items pulled through such as contact details etc. I have pulled through $this->item->link which shows a URL which is perfect. I just want to make the url clickable, so I had the following code:

```
echo "<a href='$this->item->contactlink' target='new'>";
echo $this->item->contactlink;
echo '</a>';
```

This link doesn't work, stays within the site with a 404 and the URL looks like: http://domain.co.uk/JObject->contactlink

What can I do or have I missed to get the link clickable?

Kind regards
Liam

Comment: What does the html look like after the php runs?

Comment: The page loads fine, it's just that if you hover or click the link it tries to go to http://domain.co.uk/JObject->link rather than going to the actual link. Obviously that url doesn't exist so it shows 404.

Comment: in your question you say this: _"I have pulled through $this->item->link which shows a URL which is perfect"_ is it this: `$this->item->link` or this: `$this->item->contactlink` . In either case, can you provide the `echo` results of each one?

Comment: im assuming your'e working on Joomla.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->item->contactlink; ?>" target='_blank'>
    <?php echo $this->item->contactlink; ?>
 </a>
```

Or shorter version:

```
 <a href="<?= $this->item->contactlink; ?>" target='_blank'>
    <?= $this->item->contactlink; ?>
 </a>
```

Target='new' may be part of the issue - I believe target=_blank is standard. Not 100% on the issue, without seeing how you are building '$this'. Also pulling the php elements away from the html helps clear the link reference. Maybe there is an extra quotation for the link?

Comment: "try" is not an answer. Provide details, and explain why this is an answer and how it solves their problem.

Comment: @CodeGodie If it worked it's definitely an answer. But I've added more explanation for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: its not for my viewing pleasure. This is a community. When you write an answer you need to write it in a way that helps the Original Post but also any future users looking for that same answer. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, thank you. The code was within an if statement and I was using echos, so I added ": ?>" to the end of the if opening and could use normal HTML. I then added your code and it worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting a PHP parser glitch: It's not "greedy". Using a nested object reference, or multidimensional array, in a `"`-quoted string only parses the FIRST "dimension" of the object or array as part of the object/array:

```
php >  class z { function __toString() { return get_class($this); } }
php > $x = new z();
php > $x->foo = new z();
php > $x->foo->bar = new z();
php > echo "$x // $x->foo // $x->foo->bar";
z // z // z->bar
```

Note the `z->bar` on the final part of the echo. The PHP parser saw `$x->foo` and STOPPED parsing there, leaving `->bar` as plain text, and not part of the object.

You need to use the `{}`-extended strings syntax:

```
php > echo "$x // $x->foo // {$x->foo->bar}";
z // z // z
```

Note how `->bar` didn't get output.

And ditto for a arrays:

```
$foo['bar']['baz'] = 'qux';
echo "$foo[bar][baz] {$foo['bar']['baz']}";
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in php shell code on line 1
Array[baz] qux
```

Note how `$foo['bar']` became the word `Array` in the first portion, while `qux` was properly output in the second.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Marc. I'm a little lost but will have to read more about it!